# Множественный вызов ссылочной функции (Callback must be a function. Received undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Имеется следующий код:

```
function test () {
    this.defaultCallback = {}
    this.setCallback = function (callback) {
        this.defaultCallback = callback
    }
    this.getDataIntervally = function () {
        // get data
        let data = 'baz'
        setInterval(this.defaultCallback(data), 1000)
    }
} 

function bar (data) {
    // do something with data
    console.log(data)
}

let a = new test()
a.setCallback(bar)
a.getDataIntervally()
```

После инициализации экземпляра `test` в поле `defaultCallback` присваивается внешняя функция `bar`. Однако при попытке вызова в `test` функции `getDataIntervally` обращение к функции `bar` происходит только первый раз, остальные вызывают Exception.
Ниже лог:

```
baz  // первый успешный вызов функции
node:internal/validators:224
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(callback);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
    at setInterval (node:timers:210:3)
    at testclass.foo (C:\Users\user\www\infocenterv2\test.js:9:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\www\infocenterv2\test.js:20:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)        
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}
```

Кто-то сталкивался с подобной ошибкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setInterval(this.defaultCallback(data), 1000)

В такой конструкции в setInterval первым аргументом передаётся результат выполнения `this.defaultCallback(data)`, а должна передаваться ссылка на функцию.

Делайте вот так:

```js
function test() {
  this.defaultCallback = undefined;
  this.setCallback = (callback) => {
    this.defaultCallback = callback;
  };
  this.getDataIntervally = () => {
    let data = 'baz';
    setInterval(() => this.defaultCallback(data), 1000);
  };
}

function bar(data) {
  console.log(`<bar> data="${data}"`);
}

let a = new test();
a.setCallback(bar);
a.getDataIntervally();
```

И используйте "[стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)", чтобы не терять контекст.

---

Вопрос: сильно ли изменится код при использовании конструкции class с геттерами и сеттерами?

Ответ:

```js
class Test {
    #__defaultCallback;
    get defaultCallback() {
        return this.#__defaultCallback;
    }
    set defaultCallback(fn) {
        this.#__defaultCallback = fn;
    }
    getDataIntervally() {
      let data = 'baz';
      setInterval(() => this.defaultCallback(data), 1000);
    }
}

function bar(data) {
  console.log(`<bar> data="${data}"`);
}

const a = new Test();
a.defaultCallback = bar;
a.getDataIntervally();
```

Comment: Нашел ответ параллельно с утратой контекста при выполнении функций с прерыванием. Вопрос: сильно ли изменится код при использовании конструкции class с геттерами и сеттерами?

Comment: добавил в ответ пример